# How do I move the Window buttons from left to right?

Tags: themes, window-buttons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I move all the window controls to the right?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174292/how-can-i-move-all-the-window-controls-to-the-right)

How can I move the window buttons to the right?