# How can I disable the minimize button?

Tags: unity, customization, window-buttons, usability

When I accidentally minimize windows in Unity it's so hard to find them I usually don't even bother and just open a new one instead.

How can I get rid of that terrible button so I don't ever click it by accident again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Ubuntu 12.04 and newer

Set the GSettings key `button-layout` in schema `org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences` to `close,maximize:` by using [dconf Editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-and-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it) or by running:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close,maximize:'
```

Answer (score 4):

## Ubuntu 11.10 and earlier

Your question is variation of the linked question.

[image]

Using `gconf-editor` you can remove `minimise` from the key shown and the minimise button will not appear in your windows.

---

Linked Question:

1. [How do I move the Window buttons from left to right?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579/how-do-i-move-the-window-buttons-from-left-to-right)