# How to move window control buttons to the right?

Tags: 12.10, window-buttons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I move all the window controls to the right?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174292/how-can-i-move-all-the-window-controls-to-the-right)

Is there a way in 12.10 to move the close, minimize and maximize buttons back to where they belong (on the right)?

Comment: It's not a duplicate because in 12.10 there is no apps->metacity key in dconf-editor. So the soulution should be different from 12.04