# How do we get traditional Ubuntu windows buttons?

Tags: gnome

After having installed Ubuntu GNOME remix we only have a windows close button on the top right corner:

[image]

From Ubuntu/Unity I got used to have the windows button on the left side including minimize and maximize buttons.

How can I get this layout in Ubuntu GNOME remix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu GNOME remix uses the GNOME3 shell. This will override the button layout from the windows manager preferences.

To have all windows buttons on the left side as it is in Ubuntu/Unity we can run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides button-layout "close,minimize,maximize:"
```

or any other button layout. Also see this question:

- [How can I move all the window controls to the right (or left)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174292/how-can-i-move-all-the-window-controls-to-the-right)

From the GUI we can run **dconf-editor**, browse to the key *org.gnome.shell.overrides* to replace the entry `:close` with our custom key `close,minimize,maximize:` for the traditional button layout:

[image]

**Note:** as soon as we change the button layout from the GNOME Tweak tool it will be moved back to the right side.