# How to move window control buttons to the right

Tags: unity

How to move window control buttons to the right in 14.04? The previous solutions seems not to work in 14.04.

Note:
Please **do not** mark this question as a duplicate of [174292](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174292), as 174292 is about 12.04. Now, with 14.04, the situation is completely different.