# Windows control buttons problem

Tags: 12.04, window, tweak

I have tried to move windows control buttons using gconf-editor. 
It worked partially; Now when windows are not maximied X/Minimize/Maximize buttons are on the right side, but as soon as the windows are maximized it goes back to right.
What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Per design the Unity global menu will always be on the top left, including Windows buttons on maximized applications. You may want to [disable global menu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/how-do-i-disable-the-global-application-menu)

Comment: Will this transform it to right?

Comment: Yes, if you had moved the windows controls to the right they will stay there on maximized windows too but you will lose the global menu, i.e. all application menus will always be on the application windows like it was in earlier days.

Comment: Can you give me the full guide to move them to right? I posted this question in the first place since my result ended up having window controls on the right unless it was maximized :D

Comment: Did you see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/174292/how-can-i-move-all-the-window-controls-to-the-right-or-left?

Comment: I'll try and report ;)

Answer (score -2):

Try this on your terminal:

```
sudo su
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
```

It will delete gnome configuration and resets everything !

Comment: But I do not want to reset, because resetting will return everything to left side, I want windows controls to be on the right side, like in windows?

Also using this command absolutely did nothing it just returned "root@my-computer-name"

Comment: -1 because: i) sudo is not needed here and `sudo` should be avoided unless it is actually necessary; and, more importantly ii) this will completely delete _all_ configuration settings, not only the ones the OP wants changed.

Comment: Well I actually, reverted the change now everything is in left, I really wish ubuntu gave us an option to freely customize it.