# How to move window buttons to right side in 14.04 gnome fallback

Tags: ubuntu-tweak, window-buttons

Ubuntu Tweak doesn't seem to give me this capability, I can change theme stuff but those buttons are fixed on the left side

Comment: Doesnt any of these answers work? http://askubuntu.com/questions/174292/how-can-i-move-all-the-window-controls-to-the-right-or-left

Comment: Nothing in tweak changes it, so far I should say. And gconf does nothing now.

Comment: are you using fallback/flashback with compiz or metacity?

Comment: Note - I've tested this and this answer works in 14.04 compiz flashback - http://askubuntu.com/a/209574/14356

Comment: Thank you sir! It worked, and I have fallback not flashback

Comment: I used gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'