# How to change the location of the 'close' and 'minimize' window buttons?

Tags: unity, windows, software-recommendation, gui

I want to change the location of the  'close' and 'minimize' window. 
The default location is on upper left - and I want it to be on upper right.

Screenshot attached [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/174292/how-can-i-move-all-the-window-controls-to-the-right-or-left

Comment: It's impossible right now. Our only chance is to vote on [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1622043).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `unity-tweak-tool`

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Now go to `Appearance` > `Window Controls` and set it to `Right`

[image]

Comment: done it - but i can't save it .. and i don't see any change.

Comment: Try a reboot to restart the window manager.

Comment: Ubuntu Tweak 0.0.7 [no longer has an option to change the location of the window controls](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool/+bug/1309942/comments/8). It's also no longer maintained.

Comment: @DanDascalescu He said unity-tweak-tool, not ubuntu-tweak. They are different

Comment: No `Window Controls` anymore in Unity tweak too

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `gnome-tweak-tool`.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
$ sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Than you go to Window Titlebars and change the option by placement to left.

Comment: You are answering an extremely old question of when ubuntu used unity. So your's is not the correct answer, refer to the accepted answer for the correct solution (unity-tweak-tool).