# Why are the window buttons on the left?

Tags: gui

MS-Windows cribbed the original X-Windows button layout. Then for some unknown reason Ubuntu puts them on the left!!!

You don't change the layout of your keyboard every time you change your operating system, so why change the window button layout?

Comment: Would an explanation be acceptable, or are you looking for instructions on how to move the buttons back to the right? (or is this just to express/vent your frustration, and no explanation is necessary?)

Comment: Everybody has their own preference and design choices - you can, however, [move the buttons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174292/how-can-i-move-all-the-window-controls-to-the-right-or-left)

Answer (score 4):

Having windows buttons on the left side is not really unusual:

[image] Apple Macintosh

[image] MS Windows 1.0

[image] Atari TOS

[image] Apple OSX

Coming from an Atari ST I immediately felt at home with Ubuntu's windows buttons on the left. For me it was and still is the right place. I never felt comfortable with right sided Windows' buttons.

So the question should rather be why some operating systems won't let us move them to where we want them to be.

Ubuntu does not force us to live with left-sided buttons. You are free to [move them to the right](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174292/how-can-i-move-all-the-window-controls-to-the-right-or-left), just as you personally prefer, simply by choosing a windows manager different to Unity:

[image]