# 16.04 LTS changing Title Bar Buttons

Tags: titlebar, window-buttons

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04LTS, and I would like to move the Close , Max, Min Buttons to the right side. However, each of the tutorials that I have watched shows options in gconf that I do not have. I have gone thru all of the options that I have in gconf and cannot find anyway to change it. How is this done?

Comment: Did you check the options in the compiz window manager `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` ?

Comment: Answered here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/174292/how-can-i-move-all-the-window-controls-to-the-right-or-left (for an ubuntu session it's simple - you can't.