# How to shift window control buttons from left to right in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I want the minimize, maximize and close buttons on windows to be on the right side. I've been looking for a way to solve this problem, but answers on some older questions didn't work for me.

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/537858/480481) says it can be done using Unity Tweak Tool, whereas the "top" answer claims it's not possible.