# How to move window buttons from left to right side of title bar in Gnome Classic?

Tags: themes, gnome-classic

How to move the window buttons (close, minimise, maximise) from the left side of the title bar to the right side in Gnome Classic 12.10? gconf-editor (apps > metacity etc) doesn't work. Nor does dconf-editor nor does Gnome Tweak tool.

Comment: Try taking a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/579/how-do-i-move-the-window-buttons-from-left-to-right).

Comment: Thanks but I've already seen that question though I did confuse Gnome Tweak with Ubuntu Tweak and now see they are different.

Comment: So does Ubuntu Tweak not work?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that I didn't realise Gnome Tweak and Ubuntu Tweak were different - not until I saw the screenshot you added below - so I just assumed Ubuntu Tweak was the same as Gnome Tweak and therefore wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, I knew what you meant, I was wondering if you had them straight in your question or if you were saying Ubuntu Tweak didn't work but had called it Gnome Tweak.

Comment: Apparently Ubuntu Tweak no longer contains this setting. Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using Ubuntu Tweak.

To install, run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

For more information see [How do I install Ubuntu Tweak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak).

Open Ubuntu Tweak, go to the Tweaks tab and click on Window. Then set the window control button position to be right.

[image: Ubuntu Tweak]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, that does help. Why isn't Ubuntu Tweak in the Ubuntu repository but Gnome Tweak is?

Comment: People have worked on trying to get it included, but there are several reasons that it hasn't yet, including the the ability of an official application to be able to add unofficial repositories to the system. For more information, see the [request for inclusion](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/252140).